# Best way to speed up calculation of sum of squared residuals in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-fitting

I am currently writing some python code for data analysis in which I unfortunately have to use brute-force search for the best fit. I am using a `numpy` array `exp` of dimension `M x N`. Each of the `N` columns represent a single trace of experimental data of length `M`. The actual size of the array is usually in the range of `(2500 x 15000)`.

Before performing the fit I calculate an `numpy` array `cal` of possible solutions of dimension `M x Z` (usually the size in the range of `(2500 x 20000)` or larger. To find the best fit I iterate over the experimental data and calculate the sum of squared residuals for a subset of of the calculated possible results. The subset commonly consists of 1000 traces. This currently looks somewhat like the following minimal example:

```
for i in range(1,exp.shape[1]):
    minIndex = max(bestIndeces[i-1]-maxIndexDelta,0)
    maxIndex = min(bestIndeces[i-1]+maxIndexDelta, 2499)
    SR = np.power(cal[:,minIndex:maxIndex]-exp[:,[i]],2)
    SSR = np.sum(SR,axis=0)
    bestSSRs[i] = np.min(SSR)
    bestIndeces[i] = int(np.argmin(SSR) + minIndex)
```

However, this is not a very fast calculation. What would be the best way to speed this calculation up? It would be good to keep on working with numpy arrays. Apart from that any changes or additional libraries would not be a problem to include.

Comment: Why do you use a subset of 1000 traces?

Comment: Why are you limited to brute force? Could you try using something like `scipy.optimize`?

Comment: To add to james' comment, you can minimize the sum of residuals.

Comment: After finding the fit for the first trace I know that in the following traces the correct result is in a certain subset. Using this smaller subset considerable speeds it up.

Comment: I am limited to brute-force because there are many of local minima of the SSR but I need to make sure to find the global minimum.

Comment: would `scipy.optimize.basinhopping` work for you? also, perhaps a genetic algorithm might help too

Comment: I am afraid `scipy.optimize.basinhopping` will not help. Calculation of the the theoretical traces is quite expensive and I all theoretical traces are viable for all experimental traces. Are there any possibilities speeding this code up via cython or numba?

Comment: I just tried using `scipy.optimize.basinhopping` and as I expected the actual calculation of the traces is computationally too expensive for a normal fitting algorithm. It could work with trying to fit with integers (which represent the index of the trace) and strict upper and lower bounds but this is not supported by `scipy`